# Why there is no positive charge on the inner surface when putting a positive charge in a conducting sphere off center?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, field-theory

[image]

[image]
This is the answer. My question is why the integral of E is not zero if there is positive charge on the inner surface when the field lines end on the shell. And why the integral of E is zero when all charges is negative on the inner surface, the field lines also ends on the shell. What is the difference between these two situations?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/217325/253727

Answer (score 0):

Both your questions are answerable by noting that the field inside the *ideal* conductor is zero, and all field lines ending on the conductor are perpendicular to its surface.

If there was positive charge on the inner surface then a field line coming out of that charge must end on the surface because there is no where else where a negative charge can be in this set up. But this cannot happen because any closed contour integral of $\mathbf E$ is zero, it is a static field, but the integral along a field line connecting a positive charge with a negative charge is not zero and if you close the contour inside the conductor whose integral is zero, you would get a closed contour over which the integral of $\mathbf E$ would not be zero.

When you calculate the integral from $q$ to any point of the surface along the field line connecting it to some negative charge, you are not calculating  a closed contour, and if you close it by a path through the metal along the surface and coming out at another surface point, finally closing the loop with field line from the negative surface charge to $q$, the contour integral will be zero showing that the potential of at every point of the conductor surface is the *same*.

Comment: It’s clear. Many thanks.